# How to add custom JavaScript in laravel application

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hi guys in my laravel project I have some javascript helpers function that utilizes `jquery` I want to extract to a separate place that all parts of the application can use. These are the function stored in `helper.js` :

```
// bootbox function to delete records
// it utitlizes the bootbox library


window.bootbox_delete = function (message, route, row) {
    // body...
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: message,
        title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete !",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "No",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function callback() {
                    $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Delete!",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function callback() {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        url: route
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        bootbox.alert('<b>' + data.name + '</b> successfully deleted');
                        //removing the row that have been deleted
                        jQuery(row).fadeOut('slow');
                    }).fail(function () {
                        bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrong .... Please contact administrator');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


// function that displays notification
window.notify = function(message) {
    // body...
    $.notify({
        icon: 'fa fa-check',
        message: message
    }, {
        type: 'success',
        timer: 4000,
        offset: 20,
        spacing: 10,
        z_index: 1031,
        delay: 5000,
        placement: {
            from: "top",
            align: "right"
        },

        animate: {
            enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
            exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
        }
    });
}
```

What I have done is that I added `helper.js` to `resources/assets/js` and compile to `public/js/app.js` with `npm run dev` but whenever I tried to see if things are working I get these errors:

> notify is not defined
>
> bootbox_delete is not defined

Comment: Can you show how your including `helper.js` in your `app.js` file? I.e. are you requiring `helper.js` file in your `app.js` file or are you compiling it in your `wekpack.mix.js` file? Either can you show the code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get these function to work globally you will just need bind them to the `window` object :

```
function notify(message) {
```

becomes

```
window.notify = function (message) {
```

and

```
function bootbox_delete(message, route, row) {
```

becomes

```
window.bootbox_delete = function (message, route, row) {
```

---

To install notify.js you'll need to run

```
npm install notifyjs-browser --save
```

(or if you're using `yarn`)

```
yarn add notifyjs-browser
```

Then you should just need to require the package at the top of your `helper.js` file using

```
require('notifyjs-browser')
```

---

**Helper.js**

This is what your `helper.js` should look like now:

```
require('notifyjs-browser')

// bootbox function to delete records
// it utitlizes the bootbox library
window.bootbox_delete = function (message, route, row) {
    // body...
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: message,
        title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete !",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "No",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function callback() {
                    $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Delete!",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function callback() {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        url: route
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        bootbox.alert('<b>' + data.name + '</b> successfully deleted');
                        //removing the row that have been deleted
                        jQuery(row).fadeOut('slow');
                    }).fail(function () {
                        bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrong .... Please contact administrator');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


// function that displays notification
window.notify = function (message) {
    // body...
    $.notify({
        icon: 'fa fa-check',
        message: message
    }, {
        type: 'success',
        timer: 4000,
        offset: 20,
        spacing: 10,
        z_index: 1031,
        delay: 5000,
        placement: {
            from: "top",
            align: "right"
        },

        animate: {
            enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
            exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In what file do I stored `helper.js` and where do I do the binding?

Comment: @NathanSiafa Literally the ones in your helper.js file.

Comment: your method seem to work but now I'm getting `$.notify is not a function` I do have jquery included in my master layout.

Comment: @NathanSiafa Have you used npm to add `Notify.js` to your app or are you using a cdn... (or something else)?

Comment: Notify.js is a javascript library for displaying notifications. I have it reference in my view like this `<script src="{{ asset ("/bower_components/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js") }}"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, I know what it is :) Just make sure you're pulling that in before `app.js`.

Comment: can it be install through npm? If so, how do I reference it in my project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149215/discussion-between-ross-wilson-and-nathan-siafa).

Answer (score 0):

If it is saying that function is not defined then chances are that you are not including right JS file. Can you please share code where you are including your JS file and check also in the console in dev tool if you see a 404 error, maybe you are including file but from the wrong directory.